# c - Find gray pixel in BMP image using C

Tags: c, image, bmp

**[Edit]** Now I can allocate the pixel array to get the 2-D array of my BMP picture.

But I don't know how to count the Red Green or Blue pixel of that picture because they need 3 bit to store color RGB.

I am trying to count how many bit of gray pixel in my picture using C.
I have already opened the BMP file using structure and can read all the details of the bmp file, like the height, width...

**[edited code too]**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma pack(push)  // push current alignment to stack
#pragma pack(1)     // set alignment to 1 byte boundary

typedef struct
{
    unsigned short int Type; /* Magic identifier */
    unsigned int Size; /* File size in bytes */
    unsigned short int Reserved1;
    unsigned short int Reserved2;
    unsigned int Offset; /* Offset to data (in B)*/
}HEADER; /* -- 14 Bytes -- */

typedef struct
{
   unsigned int Size; /* Header size in bytes */
    int Width;
    int Height; /* Width / Height of image */
    unsigned short int Planes; /* Number of colour planes */
    unsigned short int Bits; /* Bits per pixel */
    unsigned int Compression; /* Compression type */
    unsigned int ImageSize; /* Image size in bytes */
    int xResolution;
    int yResolution;/* Pixels per meter */
    unsigned int Colors; /* Number of colors */
    unsigned int ImportantColors;/* Important colors */
}INFOHEADER; /* -- 40 Bytes -- */
    typedef struct
    {
        unsigned char Red;
        unsigned char Green;
        unsigned char Blue;
    }PIXEL;
#pragma pack(pop)   // restore original alignment from stack

int main()
{
    HEADER data;
    INFOHEADER data2;
    PIXEL pixel;

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("lena512.bmp","rb");

    fread(&data,sizeof(HEADER),1,file);
    //read IB+NFOHEADER data into data2
    fread(&data2,sizeof(INFOHEADER),1,file);


    printf("Height: %d\n",data2.Height);
    printf("Witdh: %d\n" ,data2.Width);

 //Allocate space for pixelarray
    PIXEL **pixelarray;

    int r=0,c=0,rows=data2.Height,columns=data2.Width;

    pixelarray= malloc(rows*sizeof(PIXEL *));

    for(r=0; r<rows; r++)
    {
        pixelarray[r]=malloc(columns*sizeof(PIXEL));
    }

    //fill pixel array with pixel structs
    int pixelnum=0;

for( r=0; r<rows; r++ )
{
for( c=0; c<columns; c++ )     // read pixel data from image
{
    fread(&pixelarray[r][c].Red , 1, sizeof(PIXEL), file);
    fread(&pixelarray[r][c].Green , 1, sizeof(PIXEL), file);
    fread(&pixelarray[r][c].Blue , 1, sizeof(PIXEL), file);
    if(pixelarray[r][c].Red=pixelarray[r][c].Green=pixelarray[r][c].Blue)
        pixelnum++;

}
}
printf("Gray num: %d\n",pixelnum);

fclose(file);  //close the files prior to exiting
}
```

**[edit]**
**this part I found on the internet, why they put .Red after the 2-D array?**

```
fread(&pixelarray[r][c].Red , 1, sizeof(PIXEL), file);
fread(&pixelarray[r][c].Green , 1, sizeof(PIXEL), file);
fread(&pixelarray[r][c].Blue , 1, sizeof(PIXEL), file);
```

But then I don't know how to access the Color pixel level of my image anymore. Can anyone help me for this?
I think I should make one more struct for the pixel but as I've found on the forum there is just red, green and blue but no gray value. Sorry for not knowing anything...

Comment: I got the value 14 for HEADER and 40 for INFOHEADER, What does that mean? @dbush

Comment: That is the size of each packed `struct` in bytes.

Comment: yeah but I don't know how to get the pixel color value, that bugging me alot, I've try to read the wiki but can't understand much from that...

Comment: I suggest you use some kind of paint program to create a known small image, and use that to figure it out, knowing its size, colour depth etc. Use a width that is not a multiple of 4 pixels, so you can see where the encoded pixel row length is different from the image width.

Comment: i am currently using a Lena picture which have all the details specified.
I know all the picture stats but don't know how to implement a program to count the number of gray pixel :(

Comment: It's a cannon to kill a bug, but every time I want to deal with images in any format, I use OpenCV - http://www.opencv.org . There, you can read a `Mat` with `imread` and get directly any pixel you would want...

Comment: A gray pixel will have its red, green and blue components the same value. They will either be encoded directly as consecutive bytes in the image array, or they will be in a palette which is a lookup table for the (typically) 1-byte unsigned pixel value.

Comment: The Lena image is a standard image. It is color (e.g. each pixel is 24 bits and RGB). So, is your image file already reduced to grayscale? For your purposes, what is "grey" for an 8 bit pixel value in the 0x00-0xFF range? (e.g.) Grey is 0x40-0x70? It would be better to generate a simple image that has an known/incrementing pattern so you can verify you are accessing the pixels correctly, particularly ones starting on row 2+. Try using a paint program to generate the simpler image.

Comment: Yeah I will try it now.

Comment: Take the BMP file loader from the Baby X resource compiler, https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/babyxrc/tree/master/src (It's bmp.c, bmp.h). There's more to loading a BMP than just loading in the header struct.

Comment: I have take a look into this but we should have to do it ourselves and actually I don't understand the cde in there

Comment: I've been edited the question, could someone please help me?

Comment: I believe there should only be one single `fread(&pixelarray[r][c], 1, sizeof(PIXEL), file);` in the final loop, and not three. This is because the `PIXEL struct` is already 3 bytes big. You should maybe check your compiler has not padded your PIXEL to align any boundaries - I mean check `sizeof(struct PIXEL)==3`.

Comment: Also, BMP files are sometimes padded on each line to make multiples of 4. If your image is 512x512 it's probably ok for this image, but you should be aware it may need checking for images where the width is not a multiple of 4.

Comment: yeah, so that is a little confusing, so after I allocate the memory for the pixel array.
I try the 2 for loop to dig in the data part. But I don't know about the 
    read(&pixelarray[r][c], 1, sizeof(PIXEL), file)
I think a RGB channel must have 3 element in it not 2, and how to count how many Red pixel for example. Could you suggest anything @MarkSetchell

Comment: Your `PIXEL` struct already has 3 bytes in it - a Red one, a Green one and a Blue one. Please print and check `sizeof struct PIXEL` it is 3.

Comment: You could also do `ftell()` after every `fread()` and print the file position, then you should be at the end of the file when you have read all your data and it should finally report the same as your file size.